range of "UByte.MIN_VALUE..UByte.MAX_VALUE" is not in line with expectations
I try to iterate from 0 to 255, the range of unsigned byte, this is my code
for (b in UByte.MIN_VALUE..UByte.MAX_VALUE) {
    // do something with b
}

but why it iterate from 0 to 2^32-1, the range of unsigned int?
is there's a hidden automatic type conversion?
I tried to obverse the size of this range, code:
val range = UByte.MIN_VALUE..UByte.MAX_VALUE
println(range.toList().size)

it output "256"
it's inconformity with the iterate code

I think you have just found a compiler bug!
Normally for a for loop like this, the compiler would generate code that gets the iterator from the UIntRange, and does a while (iterator.hasNext()) loop.
However, looking at the JVM bytecode generated (this behaviour cannot be reproduced on Kotlin/JS), it seems like the compiler tries to optimise this into C-style for loop similar to the following Java (pseudo)code:
for (UInt b = UByte.MIN_VALUE ; b <= UByte.MAX_VALUE ; b++) {
    // ...
}

However, instead of doing b <= UByte.MAX_VALUE, it generated b <= UInt.MAX_VALUE. Here is a sample of the bytecode:
 5: iconst_0
 6: istore_1
 7: iload_1
 8: iconst_m1
 9: invokestatic  #18                 // Method kotlin/UnsignedKt.uintCompare:(II)I
12: ifgt          28
15: iload_1
16: istore_2
17: iload_2
18: iconst_m1
19: if_icmpeq     28
22: iinc          1, 1
25: goto          15
28: return

Notice the iconst_m1, this pushes -1 as an int (which is the max value of an unsigned int).

To achieve the correct result, you can assign the range expression to some local val first, so the compiler does not do this optimisation (though this is not technically guaranteed).
This clearly violates what the Kotlin Specification says a for loop should do. According to the spec, the for loop is equivalent to:
when(val iter = (UByte.MIN_VALUE..UByte.MAX_VALUE).iterator()) {
    else -> while (iter.hasNext()) {
        val b = iter.next()
        // loop body goes here...
    }
}

But this only loops from 0 to 255, which is correct.

I'm sorry that I am a junior programmer and cannot deeply understand your answer to continue the communication. Can I transfer this question to you to deal with? Like to submit to Jetbrains?

by the way, I think I shoud attach more information about my programing env:
IDEA IU-241.14494.240
IDEA bundled kotlin 1.9.23
oracle jdk build 17.0.10+11-LTS-240

@Eeeeee I have submitted a bug report here.

I have accept your answer, thanks for reporting this issues.
according to your suggestion, I tried different codes:
val uByteRange = UByte.MIN_VALUE..UByte.MAX_VALUE
for (b in uByteRange) {
    // This example iterates correctly from 0 to 255
}

for (b in UByte.MIN_VALUE..UByte.MAX_VALUE) {
    // This example does not iterate correctly
}

